# Scanned data to web page on android

Tags: android, cordova

I have a cordova based project with me that scans barcode. I was even able to call a webpage of my choice as inapp browser. Now i want the data from barcode scanning be autofilled in the web page i linked my app to.Help is appreciated!

Comment: Any suggestions is greatly appreciated. How to append the scanner results to an url and send it to the webpage and how to fill the fields from the received url. Need help!

Comment: How do i send text from hybrid(lets stick to android platform of cordova project) to a web page. According to my knowledge we can send the data through url. But i donno the exact way to append scanner results to the url and sending process. Also when i get the url in webpage i need to split the url get the main content and fill it in the boxes. Doccumentation or sample code helps. I have found a way to open required webpage through inapp browser. now the task is just sending scan results to the web page and reading them to required format in web app.

Comment: I am pretty sure someone knows this. please help. A thought and direction is what i am looking for.